# Disable "mail forward" through Java

Tags: email, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I want to disable "email forward" pro grammatically. Could you please help whether it can be possible through MS graph or through any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Graph API: `message` resource doesn't have any property where you can disable email forwarding but it should be possible to set `extended property` during sending a mail.

MAPI property which specifies whether the sender permits the message to be auto-forwarded has name `PidTagAlternateRecipientAllowed`. Type of the property is `Boolean` and id is `0x0002`. When the value of `PidTagAlternateRecipientAllowed` is `true` then forwarding is allowed, when `false` then forwarding is disabled.

To send a mail use the endpoint

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
```

with the body

```
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Test",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": "testing"
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "john.doe@microsoft.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
            {
                "id": "Boolean 0x0002",
                "value": "false"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To read the value for check

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message-id}$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id+eq+'Boolean+0x0002')
```

Resources:

[message resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

[Extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[PidTagAlternateRecipientAllowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/498f605c-6435-483d-98c2-60422b4aa902)

[Send mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)